# How to view files while they are being edited?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, edit

I have xammp set up on my computer, but I want to be able to edit a php file and view the results in real time. I've searched extensively for a program or online editor that will do this with no luck. I have noticed that on http://www.codecademy.com/ there is an editor while you edit php that updates immediately.
I just want to be able to edit my php file and view it in real time. Is there any way to do this?
If you are going to suggest an IDE I would rather it be free.

Comment: Saving in your code editor and reloading the browser is not working for you?

Comment: Many IDEs already provide this. Albeit there's no live repainting unless it's an entirely static HTML-only PHP script; anything involving database queries etc. will take a few microseconds to run. So it doesn't really make sense for every keypress. (You're thinking of Javascript+HTML editors.)

Comment: You could use NetBeans,  PHPStorm, or Dreamweaver they all support live coding, and I think there are many more  IDE's which can also do this

Comment: I like to be able to write code and see the progress so I know where I mess up and see the progress along the way. I'll look into those ide's

Comment: While(! $finished)  { write(); hitRefresh();}

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull wow I've never thought of that! Yes I know it is a bit lazy, but I just want it to update while I'm typing.

Comment: The server overhead of reprocessing the file every time you hit a key would be frightening

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.
When you have a file opened for writing it cannot be opened for writing by another program, so you have to open as write and open as read.
I'm seeing your error and I think for your problem you should open the file for writing, write, close the file and then update the view of the php file in an iframe, so it is permitted, because the file is only opened once each time.

Comment: That still doesn't solve my question of wanting to be able to see the changes immediately without needing to refresh.